# How to have all my included scripts as tabs instead of individuals in Inno Setup compiler IDE

Tags: inno-setup

Im new to Inno Setup Compiler and there an issue I'm where when I selected on the main script that includes other scripts I don't see them as tabs on the top section.

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I can't find any answers online and any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The included files show only after you compile the main script.

Go to the *Build > Compile*.